# Car struggles to pull off up hill

Tags: clutch, engine-theory, gears, towing

Could anyone help with another issue/potential issue I have? When I am parked on a hill, facing upwards, I put my car into first gear and when I pull off it feels as if I am towing something heavy, which I'm not towing nothing. It just feels like it's struggling, like the car is to heavy.

The car is a 2003 focus 1.8tdci

Cheers

Comment: Is the car manual or automatic? How many miles are on it? Have you had the injectors cleaned anytime in recent history?

Comment: Could be poor air intake. Try carburator cleaner.  Just spray it into air intake.

Comment: My very first car which I knew nothing about had a similar issue, it was driving fine, then all of a sudden it started to feel heavy, and slow down like something was pulling on the car, as luck would have it, I never changed the oil :D or transmission fluid, so maybe when you're on a hill the fluid is un-level and so low that it puts a strain on the parts and not enough pressure is dissipated

Answer (score 0):

I would consider checking all the spark plugs and the fuel injectors. Most of the time when a car struggle to do basic tasks, these are the first cause.

It is really easy to do with minimal knowledge and tools and you can find complete guides on the internet.

Comment: A TDCI is a high pressure diesel so won't have any spark plugs and the injectors aren't something I'd suggest removing.